# Transpose these two colums into rows?

Tags: vim

I've copy pasted some data from a webpage:

```
x       y
0       9
2       22.6
4       44.2
5       62.1
7       96.9
8       113.4
10      133.4
11      137.6
15      148.4
17      149.3
```

I'd like to transpose and slightly transform the data such:

```
x = 0,2,4,...
y = 9, 22.6, 44.2...
```

I know how to put commas after each column using v mode but I don't know how that could work for when I have double digits or a column with mixed length of characters.

I'm more concerned about how to transpose, if that is the command that I want?

How can I get my data into the desired form:

```
x = 0,2,4,...
y = 9, 22.6, 44.2...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the external tool `rs` installed see second approach below,
otherwise:

### Pure Vim

My approach would centre around using visual block mode with `Ctrl` +
`v` and applying the `J` command, and cleaning up with a substitution. First
select the second column in visual block and delete it, then paste it below the
x column:

```
x   
0   
2   
4   
5   
7   
8   
10  
11  
15  
17  

y
9
22.6
44.2
62.1
96.9
113.4
133.4
137.6
148.4
149.3
```

Then you can do `vipJ`, on each block, to select that data and put it on one
line (FYI: `vipJ` is going to `v`isual mode, selecting `i`nside `p`aragraph,
and then `J`oining those lines):

```
x   0   2   4   5   7   8   10  11  15  17  

y 9 22.6 44.2 62.1 96.9 113.4 133.4 137.6 148.4 149.3
```

A quick substitution `:s/\s\+/, /g` can replace spaces with commas:

```
, x, 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15, 17, 

, y, 9, 22.6, 44.2, 62.1, 96.9, 113.4, 133.4, 137.6, 148.4, 149.3
```

Then you can just clean up the extra commas, and add the `=` sign, remove the
blank line etc:

```
x = 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15, 17
y = 9, 22.6, 44.2, 62.1, 96.9, 113.4, 133.4, 137.6, 148.4, 149.3
```

If there are many columns, you probably don't want to repeat the procedure
above for each one... in that case you can probably record the above as a
macro in a repeatable way or check out the approach below.

### Using external tool rs

The `rs` tool allows you to reshape a data array, so you could filter your file
(or a visual selection, or passing a range) through the tool from inside vim
like so:

```
:%!rs -T -C,
```

The flags `-T` means to transpose, and `-C` specifies the column delimiter in
the output (a comma in our case) to produce:

```
x,0,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,15,17,
y,9,22.6,44.2,62.1,96.9,113.4,133.4,137.6,148.4,149.3,
```

Then as in the pure vim approach, you just need to do some clean up:

```
:%s/,/, /g
```

produces:

```
x, 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15, 17, 
y, 9, 22.6, 44.2, 62.1, 96.9, 113.4, 133.4, 137.6, 148.4, 149.3,
```

Then you can just clean up the extra commas and add the `=` sign:

```
x = 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15, 17
y = 9, 22.6, 44.2, 62.1, 96.9, 113.4, 133.4, 137.6, 148.4, 149.3
```

### Bonus

If needed, you could run the external command (also on a visual selection, or
passing a range) `:%!column -t` to align things nicely:

```
x  =  0,  2,     4,     5,     7,     8,      10,     11,     15,     17
y  =  9,  22.6,  44.2,  62.1,  96.9,  113.4,  133.4,  137.6,  148.4,  149.3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I got as far as `vipJ` (never used that before, what's happening there?) then when you said "Past(e) the other column back underneath:" I don't know how to do that? Need some hand holding here

Comment: I did things in a better order in the updated answer